# Pandas - Extract a phrase from one column and adding it to a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have some text data in (Column 1), and was wondering if I could extract a specific sequence from the rows in that column and add them to a new column.

For example:

```
  (column1)
Coke Can 300ml
Bottle 800ml
Cup
Bucket 2000ml
```

Turns into:

```
(column1)          (column2)
 Coke Can            300ml
 Bottle              800ml
 Cup                 N/A
 Bucket              20000ml
```

Basically, I want to extract every phrase with "xxml" and insert that into a new column. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is?

Comment: I think this is pretty clear? My issue was that I wanted to find a way to extract the weight values and place them in their own column.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33408403/extracting-text-from-elements-in-pandas-column-writing-to-new-column, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44464118/python-pandas-extract-a-number-from-column-into-new-column, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52171736/pandas-extract-numbers-from-column-into-new-columns, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54681095/pandas-dataframe-parse-string-column-to-extract-dates-into-new-column, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54440554/how-to-extract-a-keywordstring-from-a-column-in-pandas-dataframe-in-python

Comment: _My issue was that I wanted to find a way to extract the weight values and place them in their own column._ That's what you're trying to do, not what the problem actually is.

Comment: Ok I'll keep that in mind for further questions. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use pandas [str extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to search for numbers followed by 'ml'

```
  df['(column2)'] = df.iloc[:,0].str.extract(r'(\d+ml)')

    (column1)      (column2)
0   Coke Can 300ml  300ml
1   Bottle 800ml    800ml
2   Cup             NaN
3   Bucket 2000ml   2000ml
```

If you want to remove the 'ml' after the digits, you can use regex look behind assertion ... it will only look for 'ml' after digits and replace it with an empty string

```
df.iloc[:,0] = df.iloc[:,0].str.replace('(?<=\d)ml','')

    (column1)   (column2)
0   Coke Can 300    300ml
1   Bottle 800      800ml
2   Cup             NaN
3   Bucket 2000     2000ml
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Now, is there a way to remove the ml values in the original column?

Comment: added a solution to cover removing 'ml' values after the digit

Answer (score 1):

use [pandas.extractall](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) to extract into various columns.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    col1 = ['Coke Can 300ml', 'Bottle 800ml', 'Cup', 'Bucket 2000ml']))
print(df.to_markdown())
|    | col1           |
|---:|:---------------|
|  0 | Coke Can 300ml |
|  1 | Bottle 800ml   |
|  2 | Cup            |
|  3 | Bucket 2000ml  |

import re
df=df['col1'].str.extractall('([a-z ]+)(\d+)?([a-z]+)?',flags=re.I)
print(df.to_markdown())

|        | 0        |    1 | 2   |
|:-------|:---------|-----:|:----|
| (0, 0) | Coke Can |  300 | ml  |
| (1, 0) | Bottle   |  800 | ml  |
| (2, 0) | Cup      |  nan | nan |
| (3, 0) | Bucket   | 2000 | ml  |
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this.

```
df['new_column'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[-1] if len(x.split()) > 1 else None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    col1 = ['Coke Can 300ml', 'Bottle 800ml', 'Cup', 'Bucket 2000ml'])
)
```

the following might be what you're after here:

```py
In [13]: df.col1.str.split(' ', expand=True, n = 1)
Out[13]:
        0          1
0    Coke  Can 300ml
1  Bottle      800ml
2     Cup       None
3  Bucket     2000ml
```

However, this is splitting on the first whitespace from the right of the column values.

For this the answer you have from @sammywemmy seems best, I'm simply putting this here as it might be of interest.